# Ansible - restrict the deployment after entering a specific password (note: not an SSH password)

Tags: ssh, passwords, ansible

Ansible deploys to multiple servers: `dev`, `qa`, `uat`, `prod` etc. SSH keys are set up for all environments.

I would like to restrict the deployment to `prod` only after entering a specific password (note: not an SSH password).

How do I enforce this only while running on the `prod` inventory?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Security or prevent accidental deploys?

Comment: prevent accidental deploys

Answer (score 1):

To prevent accidental deploys you can use extra vars or environment variables (add it as your first task):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: "'prod' not in group_names or ('prod' in group_names and (allow_prod_deploy | default(false) or lookup('env', 'ALLOW_PROD_DEPLOY') | default(false)))"
        msg: "Trying to deploy to production, but allow_prod_deploy is not set!"
```

Execute prod deploy as follows:

```
ansible-playbook -e allow_prod_deploy=1 myplaybook.yml 
or
ALLOW_PROD_DEPLOY=1 ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest you can do, is to actually use an SSH password, but at the same time set up a requirement on the production servers to provide both: the password and the key for the Ansible user.

Add the following to the end of `sshd_config` and restart the SSH daemon:

```
Match User ansible
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    AuthenticationMethods "publickey,password" "publickey,keyboard-interactive"
```

(of course, replace `ansible` with the actual account name)

---

This way you don't subvert the security:

- `ansible` user must use both: password (you'd need to add `-k` to the Ansible call for production servers) and key-based authentication
- all other users must use key-based authentication (assuming you have `PasswordAuthentication no` in the general section of `sshd_config`)